# Slow performance when using high offset

Tags: jpa, spring-data

For example, I want to retrieve all data from citizen table which contains about 18K rows.

```
String sqlResult = "SELECT * FROM CITIZEN";

Query query = getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(sqlResult);
query.setFirstResult(searchFrom);
query.setMaxResults(searchCount); // searchCount is 20

List<Object[]> listStayCit = query.getResultList();
```

Everything was fine until "searchFrom" offset was large ( 17K or something ). For example, it took 3-4 mins to get 20 rows ( 17,000 to 17,020 ). So is there any better way to get it faster but not via tunning the DB ?

P/s: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: Can you add the generated SQL statement?

Comment: Probably that generated query will cause some frowning eyebrows regarding the usage of a ROWID. Fact of the matter is that the query as used is pretty terrible to go through in a paginated way; it doesn't even fetch the results in a predictable order.

Answer (score -1):

You Could use batch queries.
A good article explaining solution to ur problem is available here:
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.in/2010/08/batch-fetching-optimizing-object-graph.html

Comment: How does using a batch query solve the issue when you are already using `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()`?